# uploading video through carrierwave gem on rails 4

Tags: carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-4.1

```
Hai I am trying to upload a video through rails 4 application locally.

So that I used carrierwave gem in gemfile

Then I generated rails g scaffold video title:string description:string 

rails g uploader Video

add a column for video file parameters to our videos table:

class AddVideoToVideos < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
add_column :videos, :media, :string

models/videos

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
mount_uploader :video, VideoUploader
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
end

end
end

app/controllers/videos_controller.rb

def set_video
@video = Video.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
def video_params
params.require(:video).permit(:title, :description, :media,
:media_cache)
end

views/videos

<%= f.file_field :media %>
<%= f.hidden_field :media_cache %>
<%= f.submit "Save", :class => "btn btn-default" %>


app/uploaders/video_uploader.rb

class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
def store_dir
"uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.
id}"
end
def extension_white_list
%w(mp4 ogv avi)
end
end
```

but still I am getting error in the controller such as given below but anywhere I am not using name but still getting same error don't know why it is like that please help me somebody

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass 
 app/controllers/videos_controller.rb
respond_to do |format|
      if @video.save
        format.html { redirect_to @video, notice: 'Video was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @video }
      else

Comment: I am going through similar scenario, any solution?